# Latest versions of Python 3 and PyQt5 working on Windows XP 32bit

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-xp, pyqt5

I developed a program with Python 3 64bit and PyQt5 on Debian 64bit (of course it works on Linux and Windows 10 64bit). The problem is I cannot find the last version (if it exists at all) of PyQt5 working on Windows XP 32bit. As I have read, it seems that Python version 3.4.4 is the newest/latest to work with Windows XP, and it is currently working.

I tried `pip3 install PyQt5`, but with no luck. I get:

> $ pip3 install PyQt5
>
> Collecting PyQt5
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requierement PyQt5 (from versions:)
>
> No matching distribution for PyQt5

I looked at the official website of [PyQt5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), without luck, to find some kind of installer. It may be there somewhere, but I'm used to just making a `pip3 install [package]`, and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find an archive of earlier installers and source code on sourceforge:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/

The latest 32bit Windows installer for Python-3.4 seems to be for PyQt-5.5.1.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find the installer right there, it works as expected now! Thanks again!

Comment: I am also writing on Linux and need support for XP. I was told here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483708/how-to-install-pyqt5-wtih-python3-4-and-sip-4-19-1?noredirect=1#comment87984619_50483708 I can build SIP 4.19.1 from source needed for newest PyQt5. Later if you build with cx_freeze I found here I can modify binary exe file so visual c++ dll's from MS support XP http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=423#comment-30443