# How to install PyQt5 wtih Python3.4 and SIP 4.19.1?

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.4

I need to use Python3.4 which is installed on my XP machines. Now I am trying to install PyQt5 in Win10 with Python34. However, when I run

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

I get:

> Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement SIP>=4.19.1

Then I tried to install SIP froom PyPI [download site](https://pypi.org/project/SIP/4.19.1/#files) for SIP but it says Python version is min. 3.5. Even the oldest version 4.18 is for Python3.5.

Is there a way to use PyQt5 with Python34? Or can I run the app in XP if I use Python36 for writing and pack it with pyinstaller in one executable?

Comment: You should be able to build both SIP and PyQt5 packages from source for Python3.4. See [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html) and [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source)

Comment: Here is PyQt5 5.5.1 build agains Python 3.4 which is last supported in XP https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/